# Is a Command-line Interface an Event driven Program

Tags: events, command-line-interface

I know that it is officially not but it reacts to keyboard input which is actually an event. Can anybody give me the concert facts because I am confused.

Comment: smells like homework ..

Comment: Well actually it is but I am also curious because it is a struggle for me when I don't know something that I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason is that an event driven program operates in an 'event loop'. This is where a programming loop cycles during normal execution of the program, checking for a specific event condition and executing the logic associated with that condition. See [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) on Wikipedia. They usually don't terminate until instructed to.

Command line applications usually follow a set sequence and terminate once the program reaches the end of the code. They do not loop to check for the presence of events.